# Is it possible to get a float value with unknown decimal point?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, floating-point

I want to pass a parameter for deciding how many value should come after decimal point like below

```
int decimalpoint=2;
NSString *deciPnt=@".2";
NSString *deciPnts=@"2";
CGFloat floatvalue=4.256345;

NSlog(@"Req floatvalue= %%df",decimalpoint,floatvalue);
output should be: Req floatvalue= 4.25

or

NSlog(@"Req floatvalue= %%@f",deciPnt,floatvalue);
output should be: Req floatvalue= 4.25

or

NSlog(@"Req floatvalue= %%@f",deciPnts,floatvalue);
output should be: Req floatvalue= 4.25
```

I tried this it will not working for me..
I know it will possible by `NSLog(@"Req floatvalue= %.2f",floatvalue);`

Please share your ideas, I hope they will help me....

Comment: Why so many question marks?

Comment: And what do you mean by "by passing two parameters to get one float value????"?

Comment: Floats aren't objects, and there's isn't an "Objective-C way of doing NSLog()". Just stick with C, it won't eat you (though, demons will fly out of your nose)

Comment: If you any idea on this...

Comment: @GR. ***I HAVE NO IDEA*** because your question is incomprehensible and nonsensical. Explain ***in English*** what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had to think about the question quite a bit... Not sure if this is what you want, but you can use the variable-precision conversion specifier, `*`:

```
NSLog(@"%.*f", 2, 2.44793);
```

(Note that this is POSIX and works with `printf()` as well.)

Comment: ..It working with * ...instead of variable-precision conversion specifier *, I need to pass int value or string value to specify the decimal point number. I understand it not possible...thanks for your comments...

Comment: @GR. Then use your `int` variable instead of the constant `2` and **develop some common sense.** `NSLog(@"%.*f", numDecPlaces, 2.44793);` works equally well, isn't that obvious? (If it isn't, then go back, learn C properly and don't you dare starting Objective-C until then.)